# Разложение большого числа на произведение простых

Tags: криптография, rsa

Дано:

- Зашифрованный текст

> D\x16\x18\x17f\x11Z\xdf)x`\xfa\x9fc}\xcc\x82\xca\xba\x91]\xb0\xcazY\x19\xb6\x1fu\xe9\xfa\xbb

- Открытый ключ и значение **е**

> PublicKey(70522929974469314931544817757466358274757419346612995867321706443817159610497, 65537)

Задача: выявить уязвимости в алгоритме и расшифровать сообщение. Дана ссылка только на [модуль RSA в питоне](https://stuvel.eu/rsa) .

Я может что-то не понимаю, но для расшифровки надо ключ разложить на простые числа, что невозможно за адекватное время.

Comment: Собственно, вы сами ответили на свой вопрос в последнем предложении.

Comment: Впрочем, для 256-битного шифрования время может оказаться вполне адекватным.

Comment: `70522929974469314931544817757466358274757419346612995867321706443817159610497 = 813193982043513888556316308982892317 * 86723379085084822330632132214835775151541`

Comment: @Yaant подскажите, пожалуйста, как это было сделано? просто брутфорс?

Comment: https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM

Comment: @Yaant правильно ли я понимаю, что он сначала раскладывает на произведение простых чисел, а потом из них комбинирует 2 больших числа?

Comment: Там по кнопке "Help" сказано, какие алгоритмы используются - _This application factors numbers or numeric expressions using two fast algorithms: the Elliptic Curve Method (ECM) and the Self-Initializing Quadratic Sieve (SIQS)._ Ссылка на исходный код там тоже есть. :)